# Size of Next pointer in linked list?

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof

Hello All given a node of linked list as,

```
struct node
{
int data;
struct node* next;
};
```

Consider int with 4 bytes.What will be the size of pointer **next**?

And also i have the following ,

```
void * ptr;
printf("%d",sizeof(ptr));
```

Size of pointer is 8 bytes.

I am getting the sizeof(struct node) as 12,how is the size of **next** pointer's size in the given struct node is 12.Please help me to understand.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: `sizeof(ptr)` is always a size of the pointer, regardless of what it points to.

Comment: @AlexD So ,if a pointer is of int type where int is 4 bytes,then size of int pointer is equal to size of pointer.Thanks.

Comment: @AlexD `sizeof(char *)` need not equal `sizeof(double *)`,  `sizeof(int (*)() )`, etc.  All objects points can convert to `void *`, but that does not need they are specified to be the same size.  Same size object pointers is very common though.

Comment: @SubSea The sizeof on a `int` in not connect to the sizeof a pointer.  Either one could be larger than the other, or the same.

Comment: @chux Thanks ,Can you please give some scenarios for better understanding.

Comment: @chux I did not mean "regardless of **data type** it points to", I meant "regardless of **data** it points to". Thanks for the clarification anyway!

Comment: @AlexD fair enough, I did not see the subtly til now.

Comment: @SubSea [better understanding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41710224/2410359) provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(pointer)` is a constant regardless of the plain old data type it points to on most common, modern systems. Since you did:

```
sizeof(ptr)
```

and got `8 bytes` i would hazard a guess that you are on a 64bit system. This indicates to me that your `sizeof(struct node)` will be 12 bytes because you have the following:

```
struct node {
    int data; // 4 Bytes (32 bit, a common size for `int`s)
    struct node* next; // 8 Bytes, as are all pointers on your system
}; // total size of 12 bytes.
```

Comment: An improvement, but "sizeof(pointer) is a constant regardless of the plain old data type it points to. " is not backed up by the C spec, even though that is common.  Pointers to different object types may differ in size - although that is increasingly rare.

Comment: It depends on the architecture/operating mode too, for example in x86 real mode there are "near" and "far" pointers which are different sizes.

Answer (score 2):

On typical systems, the size of a pointer is independent of the size of the data it points to.  On a 32-bit system, pointers are 32 bits (4 bytes), and on a 64-bit system, pointers are 64 bits (8 bytes).

Your structure is 12 bytes presumably because it holds a 4-byte `int` and an 8-byte pointer.  However, this is platform-specific and can vary.  Many systems require values to be [aligned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) to a whole multiple of their size — that is, a 64-bit pointer must begin at an address that's a multiple of 8 bytes.  Compilers will insert padding between structure members to meet alignment requirements.

On my x86-64 Linux system, the size of your structure is 16 bytes: 4 bytes for the `int`, 4 bytes of padding to reach an 8-byte boundary, and 8 bytes for the pointer.

Comment: Disagree with "the size of a pointer is independent of the size of the data it points to" Sizes of pointers to functions are often different than pointers to objects.

Comment: `char *p;                                                                                                              double *q;                                                                                                         printf("%d %d",sizeof(p),sizeof(q));`                                                                  both will print the same value;

Comment: @subsea That may be on your platform, but is  not specified to be the same  in C.

Answer (score 1):

Size of a pointer is the number of bytes needed to store the address:

```
printf("%zu",sizeof(ptr));
printf("%zu",sizeof(struct node *));
printf("%zu",sizeof &abc);
```

Each of the above should return `8` on a machine with 64-bit addresses and `4` on a machine with 32-bit addresses.

Size of a node can be obtained by dereferencing the pointer:

```
struct node abc;
void *ptr = &abc;
printf("%zu",sizeof(*((struct node *)ptr)));
```

The above should return `12` on a machine with 64-bit addresses, as mentioned above.

Comment: `sizeof` operator returns type `size_t` which is not the same as `int`.  With `printf("%d",sizeof(ptr));`, now we are looking at 3 types `int`, `size_t`, and `void *`.

Comment: @chux, that's right and it's not good practice. But it should compile and run correctly (as in without indeterminate consequences), correct ?

Comment: No.  Better to  use `printf("%zu",sizeof(*ptr));`, that is what the `z` modifier is for, `size_t`

Comment: Could simplify to `printf("%zu",sizeof(struct node *));` or `printf("%zu",sizeof &abc);`

Comment: Yeah that would be ideal. Wanted to make it as the OP wanted. I can add these possibilities also.

Answer (score 1):

> What will be the size of pointer next?

The size is `sizeof(struct node*)`

---

Code should not be written to depend on a particular result.

The result could be 4 or 8, or 1 or 16 or others.

Writing *portable* C code relies on not know precisely the answer other than is is of some sane range like 1 to 64.

OP has not mentioned the reason for needing to know value of the size of `sizeof(ptr)`, but the answer is simply the size of a pointer is `sizeof(ptr)`.  Code should use `sizeof(ptr)` rather than a magic number like 4 or 8.

---

To *print* the size of a pointer, use

```
some_type* ptr;
// printf("%d",sizeof(ptr));
printf("%zu",sizeof(ptr));
```

> **z** Speciﬁes that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion speciﬁer applies to a `size_t`  C11dr §7.21.6.1  7

The size of a pointer like `int *`, `const int *`, `void *`, `int (*)()` may differ.  Portable code does not assume all pointers to various types are of the same size.